# How to parse string to DateTime following PC regional setting

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

The following code:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt);

textBox1.AppendText(s + "\n");
textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "\n");
textBox1.AppendText(dt.ToString() + "\n");

DateTime.TryParse(s,
                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                  DateTimeStyles.None,
                  out dt);
textBox1.AppendText(dt.ToString() + "\n");
```

produces the following output on the textbox:

```
13.09.2013 1602.38
13.09.2013 1602.38
01.01.0001 0000.00
01.01.0001 0000.00
```

Why `TryParse` can't parse the string `s` to correct `DateTime` object? I want my program to be able to correctly parse the strings formatted like `s`. How can I do that?

This is a C# WPF program running on .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Have you tried `AssumeLocal` on the styles argument? I tried your code locally, but it works as expected under my en-GB locale.

Comment: Your code work fine to me, from your output it's like something set `dt` to default value before this line `textBox1.AppendText(dt.ToString() + "\n");`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I just tried `AssumeLocal` in the last `TryParse`. The output is still the same. I heavily modified date and time format of PC. You can try to modify the date and time format of your PC and see if the code still works.

Comment: @donotalo What culture is currently "local" to you? So I can run some sample code with the correct culture. Also, what other modifications to date/time formatting on the OS have you made? Please detail this in the question.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: My PC culture is modified en-US. I modified date and time format as you can see in first two outputs in the question.

Comment: @Donotalo Ok, thanks. Yes I can reproduce this issue now.

Comment: Have you tried with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` instead of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: yes, the output is same.

Comment: @Donotalo I suspect the issue is with changing some of the format, but not all options to be consistent.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Then how can a program be written which will successfully parse a string to DateTime object respecting PC regional setting (whatever format user customized)?

Comment: @Donotalo I'm looking into it now, but it might actually be a bad format issue as opposed to a bug in `TryParse`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Then this would be very ridiculous that C# can't parse the returned value of `DateTime.Now.ToString()`! :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your `DateSeperator` and `TimeSeperator` are same. In this case it is `.`

While converting `DateTime` to string framework just places `.` in place of those seperators so converting to string works smooth.

But when parsing it back to `DateTime` when datetime parser finds `.` character It doesn't have any clue in finding whether the element is `Date part` or `Time part`. and hence it fails.

Here is the snippet reproducing the issue and shows the fix.

```
        CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("en-us", true);
        c.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = ".";
        //c.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator= ".";//this will fail
        c.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator= ":";//this will work since TimeSeparator and DateSeparator  are different.
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = c;

        string s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt);

        Console.WriteLine(s + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString() + "\n");

        DateTime.TryParse(s,
                          CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                          DateTimeStyles.None,
                          out dt);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString() + "\n");
```

Conclusion:
You should not set `DateTimeFormat` and `TimeSeparator` to the same value. Doing so gives trouble for the runtime in parsing `DateTime` so it fails. :)

Comment: Yes, I changed my time format to `HH,mm,ss` and left my date format on `dd.MM.yyyy` and this addressed the issue. Note that a time format of `HHmm,ss` would not recognise `,` as the time separator.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Am not sure about that. I think changing time format doesn't matter here Seperator for date and time matters more. I may be wrong.

Comment: I was just saying I could prove your solution via the OS settings for time, but I had to feature the separator between `HH` and `mm` for it to be detected as a separator automatically without having to make my own instance of the format info as in your example.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Got it. I feel this way it will be easy to illustrate the problem rather than pointing to change the settings via `ControlPanel`

Comment: I know, I was just putting it into the context of the OPs original question.